# add text , subtext & image in single table cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to add text , subtext & image in single table cell like this =>

http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/5451/tablevcinterface.jpg

I want add subtext below main text (e.g. => Apple in main text & iphone is subtext which is shown below Apple)
How can i add ?
Any sample code or tutorial link is helpful.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass UITableViewCell. This might be helpful. http://iappdevs.blog.co.in/tag/adding-image-to-uitableviewcell/

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can refer to [TableViewSuite sample application](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html).